# Ceiling junction box for splice

Tags: junction-box, splices

Can anyone tell me if there are any small junction boxes available out there ? I just want it for the Romex splice in the ceiling , that is it. I don't need that for any fixture.

One I found is 4 inch round, Carlon old work box 18 cu. Inch. Although it will be covered with plate, aesthetically , it looks too big.

Wires are 14/2 NM cable, just need to extend existing wire with another cable. So junction box will have only 2 NM cables inside it. I prefer round but rectangle should work too.  I need old work box.

I am open to suggestions/ideas.

Comment: Splicing how many of what size wires?

Comment: Yes, how many cables and what gauge are they?  Also, does it need to be round, or will a rectangular box work?

Comment: Remember, it has to remain accessible.

Comment: Is this for a cable extension, a repair, or some other situation, for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have attic access you can use a standard construction box and nail it th a ceiling joist and put a cover on it when done

If you do not have ceiling access a standard single gang old work box is the rectangle device you are looking for. Yes the cover has to be accessible but if you like rectangles better that is the way to go.

Comment: Yup; alternatively there is the 3/O (3" octagonal) round box, if you prefer the round cover but want slightly smaller than your 4/O box. Wire size/count is limited and they are hard to find... but they still exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a splice box, you can see if your AHJ will allow use of the Tyco in-wall splice connectors for this job.  (it's generally allowed for repairs only, not remodels).

Other than that, have a competent old-work electrician fish an entire new cable for the entire run.  If you're looking for a splice box that has a 2" cover plate, that's not going to happen.